# Is there a tool to use google analytics xml data to anticipate future web traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

is there a tool that will allow me to import my google analytics XML sheet and then give me an estimate of where my site traffic will be at a set date in the future based on said information.

Thanks.